# Get total number of records with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

MySQL has a feature for getting the total number of records a query would return without a limit, `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Does Laravel support this?

Currently I have to do it in two queries:

```
public function dataTable() {
    $bookings = DB::table('bookings')
        ->limit(Input::query('iDisplayLength'))
        ->offset(Input::query('iDisplayStart'))
        ->get();
    $count = $bookings = DB::table('bookings')
        ->count();
    return Response::json([
        'iTotalRecords' => $count,
    ]);
}
```

Not only will this be less efficient, but there's going to be a lot of redundant code once I add in all the `->where()` criteria.

Comment: Do you want this solution for Laravel Datatable package? If it, there is a basic solution.

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan No thanks. That looks overly complex for my needs.  I wouldn't mind knowing how they do the counts though -- are they all separate queries?

Answer (score 4):

For any complicated or vendor-specific queries, you generally have to pass the query directly with `DB::raw()`, e.g.:

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
    ->select(DB::raw('SQL_CALC_ROWS_FOUND ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I won't be able to use it like that. There can't be a comma after `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, which Laravel adds because it thinks it's a regular column.

Comment: laravel doesn't add the comma.

Comment: @itachi: Well something is, because the SQL it produces is "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, `created_at`, `first_name`, `last_name` from `bookings` limit 25 offset 0" which is an SQL error.

Comment: i tried `DB::table('foo')
    ->select(array(DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *')))
    ->toSql();` it returns `select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from \`foo\``

Comment: Oh... I was doing `->select(DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS'),'created_at',...)`. I guess I could put all the rows in the raw bit.

Answer (score 2):

Refined what @giaour said.

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
            ->select(array(DB::raw('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS booking_id,name')))
            ->where('...')
            ->orWhere('...')
            ->take(10)
            ->skip(50)
            ->get();

$bookingsCount  = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS Totalcount;") );
```

After SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS you can fetch count by SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS();

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue because I wanted to paginate a set of results which already included a GROUP BY and Laravel's built-in paginate() method uses COUNT(*) and doesn't work with GROUP BY.

So I ended up extending the Builder class to inject the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS right before a query is run, and run FOUND_ROWS right after. I did this by overriding the Laravel getModels() method.

I've [uploaded the code here](http://www.tero.co.uk/scripts/builder-with-pagination.php).